# Canvas 'tainted' after drawing SVG

Tags: svg, cross-browser, html5-canvas, rasterizing, taint

Similar questions have been asked, and the REASON for the problem is well understood, what I'm asking for is alternatives or work-arounds:

What I'd like to do is get a data-URL out of a canvas that has an SVG document drawn onto it.  I've tried all kinds of things, but IE9 and Chrome just won't let me have that URL as soon as SVG comes anywhere near that canvas.

I've tried:

- Canvg (doesn't support everything I need)
- Drawing the svg file directly to the canvas (content.drawImage(svg, 0 0))
- Creating a base64 string of the whole svg document, making it the source of an  and then drawing that image onto the canvas.
- Saving the svg to a file, set an  src attribute to point at the file (on the same domain), then draw that to the canvas

I'm running out of ideas.

Are there similar libraries I can try that will rasterize svg?
Is there maybe something else I can convert SVG to before drawing so that the canvas never knows SVG was involved?
Is there maybe a really simple way to do the conversion server-side with PHP or something similar?

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you have, so we can work from that?

Comment: I could, but I don't see how it would help.  The problem is not a code error, it's that I'm missing a general solution.

Comment: There's [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com)

Comment: Tried fabric.js today- It was a good idea, but didn't output anything useful when I gave it a complicated svg document (clip paths, pattern fills, viewBox, images that use dataURLs, etc).

Comment: It's hard to say why it fails without a full testcase, but it should work in Chrome according to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=279445.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rasterize SVG, here are a few projects:

- [SVG BTOA Serializer](http://getcontext.net/read/svg-images-on-a-html5-canvas)
- [Server-side rasterization from serialized SVG](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/kuje/svg_open_2009_presentation/)

Here's a browser compatibility table:

- [From SVG to Canvas and Back](http://www.svgopen.org/2010/papers/62-From_SVG_to_Canvas_and_Back/index.html#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

do three things,

1. get the SVG and parse it using XMLSerializer
2. change the canvas height and width before drawing the SVG
3. use "canvg" library to parse the SVG instead of using the canvas on browser with native canvas methods.

> ```
> //Get SVG element and then serialize it to convert to a stream of String
> var svg = document.querySelectorAll('svg');
> var base64 = [];
> for(i=0; i < svg.length; i++){
> var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
> var svgString = serializer.serializeToString(svg[i]);
> var canvas = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
> var render_width = 1000;
> var render_height = 600;
>
> //CHange/Set Canvas width/height attributes to reset origin-clean flag
> canvas[i].height = render_height;
> canvas[i].width = render_width;
>
> //Use canvg library to parse SVG and draw the image on given canvas
> canvg(canvas[i], svgString, {
> useCORS: true,
> scaleWidth: render_width,
> scaleHeight: render_height,
> ignoreDimensions: true,
> log: true
> });
>
> //Convert canvas to png formated dataURL and save the body of it
> var rawImage = canvas[i].toDataURL("image/png");
>
> //Array containing all the images in the form of base64 data URLs.
> base64ImageArray.push(rawImage);
> }
> ```

Hope this helps.